# Examples of compiled programming languages with modern features for the real world [please vote for reopen]

Tags: programming-languages, compiled

Apart from C, C++, Delphi, VB, can you put an example of a relatively "modern" COMPILED* programming language* supporting things like OO, collections, GUI libraries?
Please do not mention experimental or academic only languages, I'm looking for something **used in the real world**, for PCs 80x86, and I don't mind about the OS.

Thanks!

*UPDATED: Compiled to **native** code.

*DISCLAIMER:

- For language understand language implementation.
- For compiled to native code understand not interpreted.

Answer (score 5):

Haskell.

Source: http://www.realworldhaskell.org/

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has a lot: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages

Answer (score 2):

[Cython](http://cython.org/). Compiles to native code, is used in high performance computing, both academic and commercial, and is used to implement [LXML](http://lxml.de). GUI libraries include all those available for Python.

Also, Objective-C. That's now one of the [most popular programming languages](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html).

Comment: Never heard about it, i'll take a look. Thanks!